# weird properties of complex exponentials: $e^{i 2 \pi f(x)} = 1$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, eulers-number-e

$$
\begin{aligned}
e^{i 2\pi f(x)} &= (e^{i\ 2\pi})^{f(x)} \\
e^{i 2\pi f(x)} &=  (\cos {2\pi} + i\ \sin {2\pi})^{f(x)} \\
e^{i 2\pi f(x)} &=  (1 + i 0)^{f(x)} \\
e^{i 2\pi f(x)} &=  1^{f(x)} \\
e^{i 2\pi f(x)} &=  1
\end{aligned}
$$

True or False?

Comment: The right of the first equation is not a function. It is multi-valued, unless you are able to choose a branch. The left is a function.

Comment: Exponentials with complex numbers don't work like exponentials with real numbers.

Comment: False. $(e^a)^b\neq e^{ab},$ in general, when $a,b$ are complex.

Comment: It's similar to the problem with $$-1=(-1)^1=\left((-1)^2\right)^{1/2}=1^{1/2}=1.$$

Comment: DSP books always play this trick: (See Understanding DSP, Lyons, 3rd Edition, appendix B)

Geometric Series Identity:
$$
\sum^{N-1}_{n=0} r^{n} = \frac{1-r^N}{1-r}
$$
Thus apply complex exponential to above rule:

$$
\sum^{N-1}_{n=0} e^{-j2\pi n m / N}  = \sum^{N-1}_{n=0} (e^{-j2\pi m / N})^n  = \frac{1-e^{-j2\pi m}}{1-e^{j2 \pi m / N}}
$$

Why is it valid in this case, when "a" is a complex number?

Comment: wait a second:  $e^{i 2 \pi}$ is a real number because it equals "1"?  and I didn't specify that f(x) needed to be complex... so I would assume that f(x) is a real number function that doesn't equal $1 / 2 \pi$ … hmm...

Comment: @pico When $n$ is an integer, $(e^{a})^n=e^{an}.$ for all complex $a.$ This is because $a^b$ is, for complex $a,b,$  best seen as a multi-valued function which one value when $b$ is an integer, finitely many values when $b$ is a rational, and infinitely many values when $b$ isan  irrational complex number. Basically, $(a^b)^c$ and $a^{bc}$ **share** a value, but it is not always the principle value. The principle value if $1^x$ is $1,$ but there are many other values $e^{2\pi i m x}.$ for any integer $m.$ But when $x$ is an integer, all these values are $=1.$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Long story short :**

The property $(e^b)^c = e^{bc}$ holds for real numbers and in case of complex numbers you get such errors. (This is also the statement for any such exponent property). [Wikipedia has an article-brunch analysis such false cases.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Failure_of_power_and_logarithm_identities)

Also a side note, this question is broad. Even if it worked, without knowing what $f(x)$ is you can't say much. For example, if you allowed $f(x)$ to be equal to $\infty$ for some $x$ of its domain (Lebesgue Measure Theory cases), then $1^\infty$ is undefined.

Comment: you have shattered my whole mathematical world.  :-)

Comment: @pico Well, mathematic entities are derived based on axioms and definition which we shall follow in order to not get lost !

Comment: could you take a look at comment on main question that I just added.  thx.